# Create optional sections in Blade's templates (Laravel Framework)

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-blade

I use laravel recently, I have a problem.
I use any widget in my Blade's templates, that enables them when I needed, passing a variable to Blade, and checking:
- "if isset this variable" -> show widget
- also -> not show widget

But I don't want to use variables to do this, to avoid future collisions of many variables.

I had thought of doing a support class (simplified code):

```
class ViewHelper
{
    static $enabled_widget = [];

    function enableWidget(string $name) {
        self::$enabled_widget[] = $name;
    }

    function checkWidget(string $name) {
        if (in_array($name, self::$enabled_widget)) {
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    }
}
```

So I can enable widget from controller with enableWidget, and then return the view.
In the view, a custom directive @widget('name')/@endwidget, that use the checkWidget() function to check if enabled.

Would you recommend a cleaner solution?

Comment: Maybe this can help you: https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/blade#including-sub-views

Comment: you could just use the `@includeIf` directive in your view. It seems like the thing you're looking for. Check the docs for its usage.